# How to instantiate an object in a function from another script c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

[Unity 2019.3.5f1]

I try to instantiate an object in a called function from another script.

It works when I instantiate directly in the same script (I tried in `update()` using `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Insert)`)

It’s weird because I have no issue/error on my Unity console but I don't receive any `Debug.Log` or `print` message.

I received every `Debug.Log` until the following line is called:

```
 var monsterInstance = Instantiate(monster, new Vector3(v.x, 0.3f, v.y), Quaternion.identity);
```

Here is my code. (I removed unnecessary lines)

```
public class Spawner: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Monster customMonster;
    public static Spawner instance;

    void MakeSpawner()
    {
        ...
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Insert))
        {
            this.Create("" + Random.Range(1, 100)); // Works from insert key
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        MakeSpawner();
    }

    //Create monster with proper configuration
    public bool CreateMonster(string id)
    {
        var monster = customMonster;

        if (monster == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("the customMonster is NULL!");
            return false;
        }

        Vector3 v;
        v.x = 10f;
        v.y = 10f;
        v.z = 10f;

        print(id);


        var monsterInstance = Instantiate(monster, new Vector3(v.x, 0.3f, v.y), Quaternion.identity); // failed if called from Manager, works if called from "update"
        print("after instantiate"); // never triggered.
        monsterInstance.setID(id, true);
        monsterInstance.updateID();
        return true;
    }
}
```

My other script uses the following:

```
public class Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Manager instance;

    public GameObject monster;

    private Monsters[] monsters;


    void MakeManager() {
        ...
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        MakeManager();
    }

    public bool CreateNewMonster(string id)
    {
        print("CreateNewMonsterid =" + id);

        bool result = Spawner.instance.CreateMonster(id); //using Singleton pattern to createMonster
        print("never triggered");
        if (result)
        {
            print("success spawn. Update list");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            print("unable to create monster");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't hide console errors by pressing on the red octagon icon with a `!`?

Comment: @Iggy, yeah. I saw debug.Log, print and also errors when I misspelled a name or something.

Comment: Try the debugger, see if it's getting stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the update function in the other script to check for input. To tell it to spawn the monster. But lets say you wanted to "Spawnner" class to spawn a monster in the manager class. you would need a reference.

```
public class Spawner: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Manager manager //<--- Refrence to the manager class
    public Monster customMonster;
    public static Spawner instance;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
           manager.CreateNewMonster("MonsterID");
        }
    }
```